# C: 2D-Array doesn't get printed out from the start

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I am trying to print out the 2D-Array of my program but the output starts halfway (at Packet 18 and it doesn't print out "Packet 18:". But after that it prints out the rest properly to the end. What is going on? Since I have initialized the counter j as 0 I don't see why it would start with 18 and not display the text. What did I do wrong?

```
int i;
int j;
int s[7][50];
i = 0;

for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
{
    printf("Packet %d:\n", j + 1);
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("Value of line %d: %d", i + 1, s[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Show the declaration of `s`.

Comment: Could you post something more complete?  Including the declaration for s would help as well.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough yet to write in a file but I did limit the loop to 30 and now it displays properly so it seems like you're right. I wasn't aware that there was a limit and it's strange that it cut the outpot off at the beginning and not the end.

Comment: As things stand, `s` is uninitialized, so technically you get undefined behaviour. You are also working the array backwards from the natural order, so you will be working the cache on your machine harder than the other way around, but it looks like it should work.

Comment: may be you can use ./yourprogram | more  (on *nix)

Comment: @user3004619 : You were hitting the scrollback limit.  The scroll buffer always shows you the most recent N lines of output, where N usually defaults to something like 200 on Windows (if memory serves).  If you are indeed in a Windows console window, you can click on the icon in the upper left, go to Preferences, and find a spot in there to increase the size of that scrollback buffer.

Comment: @JoeZ: I changed the scroll buffer and now it displays correctly! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running this in a console window, and relying on the console window's scrollback to see the program's output, what's most likely happening is that the program's output is too long for the scrollback history.

Try redirecting the output to a file.  If you're running this at a command prompt under Windows, Linux or MacOS X, you can do that roughly like so:

```
myprogram > file.txt
```

(If you're on Linux or MacOS X, you might need to say `./myprogram > file.txt`.)

If you examine `file.txt` in a text editor, I think you'll see your program's full output.

Comment: Did this and the output in the output file is saved correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This code includes some initialization, and produces the output I'd expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int s[7][50];

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            s[i][j] = 100 * (i + 1) + j + 1;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
    {
        printf("Packet %d:\n", j + 1);
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            printf("Value of line %d: %d", i + 1, s[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Part of sample output:

```
Packet 1:
Value of line 1: 101
Value of line 2: 201
Value of line 3: 301
Value of line 4: 401
Value of line 5: 501
Value of line 6: 601
Value of line 7: 701

Packet 2:
Value of line 1: 102
Value of line 2: 202
Value of line 3: 302
Value of line 4: 402
Value of line 5: 502
Value of line 6: 602
Value of line 7: 702

Packet 3:
Value of line 1: 103
Value of line 2: 203
Value of line 3: 303
Value of line 4: 403
Value of line 5: 503
Value of line 6: 603
Value of line 7: 703

Packet 4:
Value of line 1: 104
Value of line 2: 204
Value of line 3: 304
Value of line 4: 404
Value of line 5: 504
Value of line 6: 604
Value of line 7: 704

...

Packet 47:
Value of line 1: 147
Value of line 2: 247
Value of line 3: 347
Value of line 4: 447
Value of line 5: 547
Value of line 6: 647
Value of line 7: 747

Packet 48:
Value of line 1: 148
Value of line 2: 248
Value of line 3: 348
Value of line 4: 448
Value of line 5: 548
Value of line 6: 648
Value of line 7: 748

Packet 49:
Value of line 1: 149
Value of line 2: 249
Value of line 3: 349
Value of line 4: 449
Value of line 5: 549
Value of line 6: 649
Value of line 7: 749

Packet 50:
Value of line 1: 150
Value of line 2: 250
Value of line 3: 350
Value of line 4: 450
Value of line 5: 550
Value of line 6: 650
Value of line 7: 750
```

Answer (score 0):

Each and every thing is right the only problem is either by mistake you put your `for()` loop in wrong place or may be you are not so aware with 2d array now according to your program

```
     int s[7][50];
```

Its mean 7 rows and 50 columns. the complete picture is seven one dimensional arrays each having fifty elements. Now to prints its data the code is

```
   1   int i,j;
   2   for(i=0;i<7;i++)       
   3    for(j=0;j<50;j++) 
   4      printf("s[%d][%d]=%d \n",i,j,s[i][j]);
```

Line 1: declaration of two local variables
Line 2: here we are first iterating zeroth array and its fifty elements one by one 
        which  we are getting from line 3.
Line 3: Now for each 1d array we are its each elements by using second `for` loop
Line 4: Just simple for `printf` function to printing the value and its position too.
If you are able to see this diagram then it is OK.

Comment: I removed your picture. It was blurry and was very difficult to understand.

Comment: I was try that one to become visible but I was fail to manage if you want the image then I will try to represent the same thing but in different manner.